# TFS linux agent ignores Build.Repository.Clean variable

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

Situation:

- TFS 2018
- build process consists of two phases -- executed on Windows and Linux agents respectively
- `Get sources` (TFVC) has `Clean` flag set to `false`

Problem:

- Linux agent (unlike it's counterpart) ignores `Clean` flag -- it always executes `tf workspace -delete`, `... -new`, etc.

I've added "print variables" step and could clearly see that `Build.Repository.Clean` is `false` in every phase.

Is there any way to fix this?

**More info:**

Setting `system.debug` to `true` produces interesting log:

```
Querying workspace information.
##[debug]tf workspaces -format:xml "-collection:<tfs-server-url>" -jwt:******** -noprompt
##[debug]No workspace matching *;Project Collection Build Service (<collection-name>) on computer <computer-name> found in Team Foundation Server <tfs-server-url>.
##[debug]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><workspaces/>
##[debug]Sources directory does not exist or is empty.
##[debug]tf workspaces ws_1_14 -computer:* -format:xml "-collection:<tfs-server-url>" -jwt:******** -noprompt
##[debug]No workspace matching ws_1_14;Project Collection Build Service (<collection-name>) on computer * found in Team Foundation Server <tfs-server-url>.
##[debug]Deleting: '/home/<user>/agent/_work/1/s'.
##[command]tf workspace -new -location:local -permission:Public ws_1_14 "-collection:<tfs-server-url>" -jwt:******** -noprompt
Workspace 'ws_1_14' created.
```

But when I login to that machine and run these commands myself (without `-jwt:... -noprompt`) -- I get correct information about `ws_1_14` workspace. Agent is being executed as daemon/service created via `sudo ./svc.sh install; sudo ./svc.sh start`. Which means problem is somewhere in that daemon's environment.

Comment: Can you queue the build with "system.debug" variable set to "true" and then share the build logs? Did you have `Clean` set to `false` both at the Get Sources and the build step? How did you map your folder?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I've updated my post with additional info. Any idea how to track down why agent gets "No workspace ..." responses from TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because my `hostname` was FQDN (instead of shortname). It is an [existing bug](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1237).

Solution is to change hostname to be short and without dots(e.g. `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname shortname`) and run build again (it will recreate workspace with short hostname in `Computer` column) and all subsequent builds should work fine.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT couldn't accept my own answer for like 24h :)